# how to FIX (not ignore) SSL error with selenium (chrome)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, ssl-certificate, undetected-chromedriver

I just want to know, why all sites, which I open via selenium webdriver have SSL certificate error? I have to keep connection secured.

I know, that problem could "solve" by adding `options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')`. But it will **ignore** error, and I need to fix it.
Actually, everything's been fine before Google Chrome updated to 115 ver.

Code:

```
import time

from seleniumwire import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
time.sleep(100)
```

And Chrome window: https://ibb.co/VDzDTYN

Comment: Do you get this error when using chrome normally, not with selenium?

Comment: @JohnGordon No, not at all

Comment: Showing us the full code, and the full error message, would be a good start.

Comment: @JohnGordon done

Comment: Try calling chrome without any options at all.  `driver = uc.Chrome()`

Comment: same error
https://ibb.co/vxNdr8D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the [selenium-wire PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#limiting-request-capture) the developers explains that:

> Selenium Wire works by redirecting browser traffic through an internal
> proxy server it spins up in the background. As requests flow through
> the proxy they are intercepted and captured...

and also explains [in the certificates section](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#certificates) that:

> Selenium Wire uses its own root certificate to decrypt HTTPS traffic.
> It is not normally necessary for the browser to trust this certificate
> because Selenium Wire tells the browser to add it as an exception.
> This will allow the browser to function normally, but it will display
> a “Not Secure” message (and/or unlocked padlock) in the address bar.
> If you wish to get rid of this message you can install the root
> certificate manually.

Summarizing, the secure connection is stablished between the selenium-wire's internal proxy-server and the website you are visiting using the website certificate, and the connection between your controlled browser and the selenium-wire's internal proxy-server uses a kind of self-signed certificate, which triggers the browser security alert. In my humble opinion and short experience using selenium-wire, it should be ok just to ignore that error or install the root certificate, as the documentation indicates.

Anyway, selenium-wire allows to add [add your own certificate](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#using-your-own-certificate). I think that if you use a valid certificate, the non-secure padlock should disappear. I haven't personally tried it.

Hopes it help, sorry for my poor English.

Comment: glad it was useful for you!